# Youtube POST upload in Java

Tags: java, youtube-api

Help :( Does anyone know how to write a POST request for uploading Youtube videos via the Youtube API, in Java?

The structure of the POST request required is described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Direct_uploading).

Unfortunately I can't use the Youtube Java client libraries, because I'm working in Android, which doesn't support them.

I have some attempted code below, but it doesn't work (I get the error that conn.getResponseCode() is null).

---

```
public void videoUpload() {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    // BufferedReader br = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;

    // InputStream is = null;
    // OutputStream os = null;
    // boolean ret = false;
    // String StrMessage = "";
    //file path

    // get filename from videoURI
    String path = "file:///sdcard/";
    String existingFileName = "video.3gp";
    File videoFile = new File(path + existingFileName);

    // String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "b93dcbA3";
    String ver = "2";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024;

    // String responseFromServer = "";

    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(videoFile);

        URL url = new URL("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[XXXXXXXXXX]/uploads");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "uploads.gdata.youtube.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
        conn.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", ver);
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Gdata-Client", clientId);
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", "key=" + developerKey);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Slug", existingFileName); //fix this
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/related;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", new Long(videoFile //and this
                .length()).toString());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

        //do we not want a boundary string here?

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");

        //and here?
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/3gpp");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.write((twoHyphens + boundary).toString().getBytes());

        StringBuilder test_xml = new StringBuilder();
        test_xml.append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n");
        test_xml.append("<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"\n");
        test_xml.append("xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\"\n");
        test_xml.append("xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\">\n");
        test_xml.append("<media:group>\n");
        test_xml.append("<media:title type=\"plain\">Test Video</media:title>\n");
        test_xml.append("<media:description type=\"plain\">\nTest Video\n</media:description>\n");
        test_xml.append("<media:category\n");
        test_xml.append("scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">People\n");
        test_xml.append("</media:category>\n");
        test_xml.append("<media:keywords>toast, election, wedding</media:keywords>\n");
        test_xml.append("</media:group>\n");
        test_xml.append("</entry>");

        dos.write(test_xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // System.out.println(test_xml.toString());
        dos.write((twoHyphens + boundary).toString().getBytes());

        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            // dos.flush();
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // byte [] buf = new byte[2048]; // Transfer in 2k chunks
        // int bytesRead = 0;
        // while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) >=
        // 0) {
        // dos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        // // dos.flush();
        // }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data
        // dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        dos.write((twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens).toString()
                .getBytes());

        // close streams
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }


    int responseCode;
    StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inStream = conn.getInputStream();
        } else {
            inStream = conn.getErrorStream();
        }

        String string;
        if (inStream != null) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            while (null != (string = reader.readLine())) {
                outputBuilder.append(string).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(outputBuilder.toString());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, outputBuilder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Apache file upload library before and it simplifies post requests for files etc. greatly:
[Apache commons file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Answer (score 1):

`conn.getResponseCode()` returns a primitive int, which can't be null. I'm not sure what kind of error you are talking about (NullPointerException?), but it is not possible that getResponseCode returns null. Perhaps conn itself is null?

If so, another exception was probably thrown by the URL constructor or by url.openConnection(). In this case, you are catching the exception and printing the stack trace to stdout, but continue to use the conn reference, which may be invalid.